# How to access env variable in functional component?

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, vue-component, vue-functional-component

I would like to define a default value if a prop is not passed to my functional component.
This default value is an environement variable.

When I try the following, compilation will throw an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'env' of undefined`

```
<template functional>
    <div class="header__small">{{ props.header_small ? props.header_small : process.env.VUE_APP_DEFAULTHEADER }}</div>
</template>
```

The same happens if I try with `parent.process.env.VUE_APP_DEFAULTHEADER`

The env variable are working fine in every other classic component accross the app. It just won't work with functional ones.
Ternary operator to define a default value works well also if I pass it any other value, just not process.env.

Comment: I know this will sound like a cliche StackOverflow answer, but functional components are made just for that reason alose, _to be stateless_.

The reason how you make `process` variable work is define it inside `data`, `computed` or return it in `methods`, which are not present inside functional components, _to be stateless_.

Comment: That's actually a pretty good answer. I didn't think I could not access process directly in any template, you can only use them in the script part of component. Well that's a shame.
Please, post it as an answer so I can mark you as accepted answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using it only as default value for a prop, did you try this?

```js
props: {
  header_small: {
    type: String,
    default: process.env.VUE_APP_DEFAULTHEADER
  }
}
```

1. `process.env.XXX` cannot be used in template directly - applies to statefull and functional components alike
2. It must always be used in the `<script>` part of the component
3. In functional components, only places it can be used is as `default` value of `prop` declaration or directly in `render()` function code

### More details

In Webpack/Vue CLI projects, environment variables are handled by Webpack [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/). It replaces any occurrence of `process.env.XXX` by some string value defined in `.env` files.
This happens at build time.

For some reason it works only when used inside `<script>` part of SFC's (JS most of the time). But we know that Vue templates [are compiled into plain JavaScript](https://magiccwl.github.io/vue-compiler-online/) too. So why is it it doesn't work also in the template ? I was trying to google a bit but didn't found any answer. So I guess it was a decision of `vue-loader` creators to not allow DefinePlugin to process the output of the Vue compiler maybe because its nature (essentially string replacement) and fear of hard to debug/support issues...

Comment: Oh well this is even better ! I didn't know the script would be interpreted by the compiler once the SFC is set as functional. Great ! Thank you !